# How to printf an exclamation point in tcsh?

Tags: escape-characters, tcsh, special-characters, printf

What's the best way to `printf` an exclamation point — `!` — in [`tcsh`](http://ports.su/shells/tcsh)?

It seems like using single or double quotes has no effect on escaping the exclamation point; and using a backslash — `\!` — does work, but then it disappears from the `history`.

EDIT:  Specifically, this issue is reproducible in combination with `savehist` — you must `exit` and reload `tcsh` to experience this issue, per my own comments from 2014-09-21T15:34Z. :-)

Comment: What command did you run? `printf '%s\n' !` seems to work normally.

Comment: Oh, so, the trick is to have `!` all by itself, and use %s, instead of simply having `!` inline?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using **`tcsh`** (not the original `csh`), you should set the `histlit` variable:

> `histlit` (+)

> If  set, builtin and editor commands and the savehist mechanism
> use the literal (unexpanded) form of lines in the history list. See also the `toggle-literal-history` editor command.

So just add a `set histlit=1` line to your `~/.cshrc` or `~/.tcshrc`.

After that, you could just backslash-quote the `!`:

```
printf 'a\!b\n'
```

Comment: Interesting, why is it not the default?  Would I miss anything by enabling this?

Comment: Because of compatibility with the original csh, which didn't have any line editor and where history expansion whas the only history recall mechanism. Setting `histlit=1` will obviously change what bangs will expand to in a new session: Eg. after `echo foo` and `!:s/foo/bar`, `!?bar` will only work as expected in the current session, not in a new session after the history was saved and restored.

Answer (score 0):

`tcsh` uses the ! character for history substitution

```
g4ur4v:~> echo $0
tcsh
g4ur4v:~> printf '!\n'
!
```

**EDIT**

```
g4ur4v:~> echo 'a\!c'
a!c
g4ur4v:~> printf 'a\!c\n'
a!c
```

Comment: `printf a!c`...

Comment: added to the answer.

Comment: This malfunctions with savehist -- after loading back the history, this extra `\!` becomes just `!`, and the thing stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ printf 'a\!c\n'
a!c
```

or:

```
$ printf '%s\n' a\!c
```

Comment: This only works prior to using `savehist` and reloading tcsh.